# Is there any way to free JVM memory in @AfterChunks in spring batch?

Tags: spring-boot, out-of-memory, spring-batch

Is there any way to free JVM memory in `@AfterChunks`? Because we are getting outOfMemory error after processing couple of records.

Is there any way to free memory after spring batch job completion ?

```java
    Public class ABC implements ChunkListener{

    private static final Logger log = oggerFactory.getLogger(ABC .class);
    private MessageFormat fmt = new MessageFormat("{0} items processed");

    private int loggingInterval = 100;

    @Override
    public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {

        int count = context.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getReadCount();

        // If the number of records processed so far is a multiple of the logging interval then output a log message.           
        if (count > 0 && count % loggingInterval == 0) {
            log.info( fmt.format(new Object[] {new Integer(count) })) ;
        }
        //String name = context.getStepContext().getStepName();
        //context.getStepContext().registerDestructionCallback(name, callback);

    }
```

How to call `registerDestructionCallback` to clean up? What are name and callback? Any reference?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force a GC in Java (`System.gc()` is just a hint to the JVM) and you should leave this to the GC.

Items in a chunk-oriented step should be garbage collected after each chunk is processed, see [Does Spring Batch release the heap memory after processing each batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616431). If you have an OOM, make sure:

- your items are not held by a processor, mapper, etc
- a chunk can fit in memory: sometimes, using the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders), the processor fetches more details about each item and you can get out of memory very quickly for the first few items

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as the author and still can't understand why. It seems that my items are held by something (I do not see anything else) but where :/ If you can check my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487684/spring-batch-import-csv-memory-leak  Thanks